# turning the non-zeros of a vector into 1's

Tags: r, if-statement, vector

suppose I create the following vector:

```
x = c(1, 3, 5, 0, 7, 8, 0, 4, 5, 0, 8)
x
```

I want to turn the non-zeros into ones:

```
for (   i in 1:length(x)   ){
if (x[i]!=0)   x[i] = 1}
x
```

This works fine, but I was wondering if anyone out there can think of a mathematical way of doing this operation instead of using the `if` statement.

Comment: Use `c` to create a vector - not `rbind`

Comment: Not unless you clarify what  qualifies as "mathematical" vs. "Not mathematical"

Comment: something like x/x doesn't work because of the 0/0 problem.    i want to be able to write a mathematical expression for this operation, if possible.

Answer (score 4):

You are overcomplicating it. No need for an `rbind`, use `c`

```
x = c(1, 3, 5, 0, 7, 8, 0, 4, 5, 0, 8);
x[x!=0]=1;
```

Comment: ok, i changed it to "c" instead of "rbind"…    

any ideas now?

Comment: The answer has what you need. `x[x!=0]=1`

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate that, but I am asking for a general mathematical way to do this operation on a vector…

Answer (score 3):

The official code-nerd way is  `y <- !!x`   :-)

Comment: Too bad there is no `nerd` badge :)

Answer (score 2):

Logically, just do:

```
as.logical(x) + 0L
#[1] 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this more mathematical?

```
x = c(1, 3, 5, 0, 7, 8, 0, 4, 5, 0, 8)
ceiling(x/.Machine$integer.max)

[1] 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1
```

Comment: Certainly creative! ;-)